Option to package Platform events is missing in my managed package in salesforce
I have created a platform event in my salesforce instance and want to add it in my managed package but when trying to add components it does not show me the option to add platform events. Am I missing anything here.

Edit1: To provide more information: My Organization type is Developer Edition

In 1GP managed packages, the Platform Event definition itself can be found under type "Custom Object".
